# i am having a issues with my check boxes they wont write or load

Tags: c#, checkbox, streamreader, streamwriter

i have 3 check boxes
Nuts
Cherries
Sprinkles

also i am using Streamwriter and StreamReader

i also have 2 combo boxes and im using an index for those to work with writer/reader

but my checkboxes wont work i am using if ele if statments for the check boxes and im out of ideas syntax is correct as far as i know (if theres another way to get my check boxes to read and write let me know) THERE HAS TO BE A DIFFRENT WAY syntax wise to make this work lets PLEASE LET ME KNOW

for some reason i get no errors in the Debugger

THIS IS my LOAD BUTTON //(THIS IS WHERE IM HAVING PROBLEMS)

```
 private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamReader sr;
        string strInput;

        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            sr = new StreamReader(ofd.FileName);

            strInput = sr.ReadLine();
            savedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(strInput);
            flavorBox.SelectedIndex = savedIndex;
            syrupBox.SelectedIndex = savedIndex;


            if (Nuts.Checked == true) 
                {

               sr.ReadLine();

                }
            else if(Cherries.Checked == true)
            {
                sr.ReadLine();
            }

            if(Sprinkles.Checked == true)
            {
                sr.ReadLine();
            }
            sr.Close();

        }

    }
```

THIS IS MY SAVE BUTTON (AND HERE TO I MUST BE MISSING SOMETHING)

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int savedIndex = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        //index for flavor of icecream
        InitializeComponent();
        flavorBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
        syrupBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
        pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.Vanilla;
        //Nuts.
    }
    // my save fucntion
    private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamWriter sw;

        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();

        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            sw = new StreamWriter(sfd.FileName);
            savedIndex = flavorBox.SelectedIndex;

            sw.WriteLine(flavorBox.SelectedIndex);

            if (Nuts.Checked == true)
            {
                sw.WriteLine();

            }
          else if (Cherries.Checked == true)
            {
                sw.WriteLine();
            }

            else if(Sprinkles.Checked == true)
            {
                sw.WriteLine();
            }

            sw.Close();
        }

    }
```

THIS IS MY REVERT BUTTON WHERE THE USER CAN OPEN A SAVED FILE THEN MAKE CHANGES AND JUST CLICK REVERT AND IT WILL GO BACK TO ITS ORIGINAL SAVED FILE WITH OUT RE OPENING THE FILE

```
private void revertToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        flavorBox.SelectedIndex = savedIndex;
        syrupBox.SelectedIndex = savedIndex;

    }
```

THIS IS MY INDEX FOR THE COMBO BOX

```
 private void flavorBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = flavorBox.SelectedIndex;

        if (index == 0)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.Vanilla;
        }
        else if (index == 1)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.Chocolate;
        }
        else if (index == 2)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.strawberry;
        }

    }
```

HERES MY EXPEREMENTAL IDEA TRYING TO GET THE CHECK BOX TO WORK

```
 private void Nuts_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(Nuts.Checked == true)
        {
            Nuts.Checked = true;
        }

        else if(Nuts.Checked != true)
                {
            //Nuts.unchecked()
        }
```

Comment: In the first section you use `sr.ReadLine();` no matter what choice, so you can leave out the choices. Same thing in the 2nd code box for the (empyt)  ` sw.WriteLine();`actions. If you keep writing the same empty line, why have choices. In the last box, you set something to true when it's true. You don't need to do that.

Comment: i changed that still doesnt help my why imy check boxes dont write from a file or read from the file

Comment: When you use a `readline`, you'll generally assign the output to a variable that you use as in `Str a= sr.ReadLine()`. When you use a `writeline` you'll have to pass it some string that you want to write as in `sw.Writeline('Strawberry');`

Comment: i think it worked it doesnt say it worked in notepad for the save i didn thave any syntax errors when when i put in the code in the ().. but when i put in code in the () after sr.readLine(Nuts) i get the errror no overload for the method readLine takes 1 arguement

Answer (score 0):

I'll tell you what i see, haven't read it all, but i see you're using 
else if's and usually when you use else's if, only one of those statements will be used (if the first one is true , it'll only do the first if and not the others ).

Now if you already knew that,
syntax wise, when you use else if's , you need to use else :

```
if (..)
{
}
else if (..)
{
}
else
{
}
```

This is wrong :

```
          if (Nuts.Checked == true)
            {
                sw.WriteLine();

            }
          else if (Cherries.Checked == true)
            {
                sw.WriteLine();
            }

            else if(Sprinkles.Checked == true)
            {
                sw.WriteLine();
            }
```

Also,you can remove the "== true" from your statements since If Sprinkles.Checked returns true, you don't have to compare it to true to know it's true, if(Sprinkles.Checked) will only work if it is true.

This code :

```
if(Nuts.Checked == true)
        {
            Nuts.Checked = true;
        }

        else if(Nuts.Checked != true)
                {
            //Nuts.unchecked()
        }
```

should be :

```
if(..)
{
}
else
{
}
```

Since there are only 2 cases that can work, if checked is true , else it is false. ( if true -> do blablabla , else ( it is false ) -> do something else).

Comment: if i dont have an else if statment it always gives me the error that its wants a semicolone after the ()

Comment: @T.J. There is no () after an else statement, it is simply else, no need to specify anything.

Comment: else Sprinkles.Checked
                {
                    sr.ReadLine();
                } gives error ; expected

Comment: @T.J. i just said that you didn't have to write anything, which means it would be 
else 
{
sr.ReadLine();
}

just compare your else if's and if, else to my answer and fix everything, it's all about your syntax.

Comment: okay.. still doesnt read or write the check boxes and im just curious how wil it know that Sprinkles was checked if its blank after the else

Comment: so you have 3 choices, if ( X.Checked ) , else if ( Y.Checked ) and else
the else will deal with  all the other opportunities but there are only 3 choices right? which means the else will replace the if ( Sprinkles.Checked )

Comment: ahhhhh i get it. so do i need to make an event hander for each check box to get them to rite mabey but make the event handler a public static so those 2 methods will call each other would that work